# File Permissions Error using load balancers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, load-balancing

I have a problem with logging. I have a class I use to log events, in my ASP.net application, to a text file. The class seems to work fine. Complications arise, though, because we are using a load balancer. We run our app on two servers. If one server fails, the load balancer will switch the web application to the other server. I can also direct the browser to specify which server to view the application on.

The problem is that when I go to one server, the application can log just fine. But if i try to switch to the other server, I get this error:

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\myServer-qa\plantshare\someFolder\myApp\Logs\2012_12_14.txt' is denied.

> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.

If i delete the file, which ever server creates it first will be fine but the other will fail. If i check the files permissions only the server that created it will have permission. Is this an issue with my code or IIS? Also, We use windows authentication. Here is the class I use to write:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class logger

    Private Shared _thisInstance As logger
    Private Shared InstanceLock As New Object
    Private Shared FileLock As New Object

    Private _path As String
    Public Property path() As String
        Get
            Return _path
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _path = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub New(ByVal path As String)
        Me.path = path
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetSingleton(ByVal path As String) As logger

        SyncLock InstanceLock
            If _thisInstance Is Nothing Then
                _thisInstance = New logger(path)
            End If
        End SyncLock

        Return _thisInstance
    End Function


    Private Function checkDir(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
        Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(path)
        Dim exist As Boolean = True
        If Not dir.Exists Then
            Try
                dir.Create()
            Catch ex As Exception
                exist = False
            End Try
        End If
        Return exist
    End Function
    Private Function checkFile(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

        Dim myFile As New FileInfo(path)
        Dim exist As Boolean = True
        Dim objWriter As IO.StreamWriter
        Dim fs As FileStream

        If Not myFile.Exists Then
            Try

                fs = New FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
                objWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(fs)

                objWriter.Close()
                objWriter.Dispose()
                fs.Close()
                fs.Dispose()

            Catch ex As Exception
                exist = False
            Finally

            End Try
        End If

        Return exist
    End Function

    'updates file
    Public Sub Logger(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal Message As String, ByVal title As String, Optional ByVal stkTrace As String = "")
        Dim sw As StreamWriter
        Dim fs As FileStream
        Dim path As String
        Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim today As String

        today = Date.Now.ToString("yyy/MM/dd")
        path = Me.path & today.Replace("/", "_") & ".txt"

        If checkFile(path) Then
            SyncLock FileLock
                fs = New FileStream(path, FileMode.Append)
                sw = New StreamWriter(fs)
                Try
                    sw.WriteLine("Title: " & title)
                    sw.WriteLine("Message: " & Message)
                    sw.WriteLine("StackTrace: " & stkTrace)
                    sw.WriteLine("Date/Time: " & now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))
                    sw.WriteLine("================================================")
                    sw.Flush()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw
                Finally
                    sw.Close()
                    fs.Close()

                    sw.Dispose()
                    fs.Dispose()
                End Try
            End SyncLock
        End If

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: sounds like the file is locked (opened by a process that never released it, then another process tries to open that file). Another possiblity is that the file is locked at that very instance and you just need to retry a few times.

Comment: I thought maybe it had to do with locking thats why I made the class a singleton and use SyncLock.  shouldnt that prevent it?  also, when i get that error, it's only for the server that did not create the log file.  Even if i get that error on the one server, using the web application from the other will not cause the error.

Comment: "Where" is the file written? In each server's `path` or do both apps write to the *same* file? Sounds like a permission issue (app1\user writes, and app2\user can't overwrite because app2\user doesn't have any permission to it).

Comment: yeah, its written to the same file for both (in the same location) on a third server.  If it is a permissions error, any idea on how to handle it?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the file be created using the IIS account.  They are both the same for the servers.

Comment: check the identity of the app pools and make sure they are the same. if one can write to it, the other should be able to as well.